Speed up a T-SQL script that uses temp tables and permanent tables and is going to migrate data across databases on the same server
I have 2 databases called Main and Archive. I need to move specific rows from Archive to Main. I have approx. 50M rows to move and they will come out of 11 tables.
The script is divided into 2 sections: data preparation and data migration. In the data prep step, I find the work orders that need to be migrated, then find all of their child data (history, shipments, etc.). All of these things are queried into temp tables, then the final data is put into 11 permanent tables, indexed, and the temp tables are emptied to clear up memory.
The data migration step loops through each work order one by one and moves it + all its corresponding data from the permanent tables and INSERTs it into the tables in the Main database.
The problem is that the data prep steps ran for 48 hours and never finished. What can I do to speed this up?
Below is the beginning of the data prep step. It shows how I prepare the driving work orders. There are 10 other sections similar to this. This whole data prep step needs to be sped up somehow.
print 'Script started!'

set nocount on
set xact_abort on

declare @Start datetime = getdate()
declare @PrepTime datetime
declare @InsertTime datetime

drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalSalesOrderArchiveCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderHistoryCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalBOMArchiveCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalSerialNumberCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalNonConformanceCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderLotArchiveCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderReworkCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderReworkStepsCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderScrapArchiveCorresponding
drop table if exists ArchiveProject_FinalShipmentArchiveCorresponding

create table ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [PrO Number] [nvarchar](20) ,
    [SO Number] [nvarchar](7) ,
    [SO Line Item] [nvarchar](10) ,
    [Priority] [nvarchar](10) ,
    [AP Part Number] [nvarchar](20) ,
    [Rev] [varchar](3) ,
    [Order Quantity] [int] ,
    [Due Date] [datetime] ,
    [Scheduled Date] [datetime] ,
    [Time Required] [smallint] ,
    [Status] [nvarchar](20) ,
    [Parent] [nvarchar](20) ,
    [Special Instructions] [nvarchar](50) ,
    [Unit Cost] [money] ,
    [Order Date] [datetime] ,
    [Open Qty] [int] ,
    [Prod Qty] [int] ,
    [Discount] [real] ,
    [Current Department Code] [nvarchar](3) ,
    [Original Due Date] [datetime] ,
    [SO Quantity] [int] ,
    [SN OK] [bit] ,
    [WeldDate] [datetime] ,
    [WeldPriority] [smallint] ,
    [WeldNotes] [varchar](100) ,
    [KitFlag] [bit] ,
    [KitNotes] [varchar](100) ,
    [StockRev] [varchar](3) ,
    [OutsideJob] [bit] ,
    [CustPN] [varchar](20) ,
    [TimeStamp] [timestamp] ,
    [GSSstamp] [datetime] ,
    [TubeNotes] [varchar](100) ,
    [SOnotes] [varchar](100) ,
    [ShortDate] [datetime] ,
    [JOB]  nvarchar(30),
    [SUFFIX]  nvarchar(30),
    [RemoteWO]  nvarchar(30),
    [Site] [varchar](3) ,
    [PART]  nvarchar(30),
    [KitFlagHighlight] [bit] ,
    [CreateDate] [datetime2](7) ,
    [CreatedByHostName] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [CreatedByLogin] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [UpdateDate] [datetime2](7) ,
    [UpdatedByHostName] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [UpdatedByLogin] [nvarchar](100) ,
    [RowPointer] [nvarchar](36) ,
    [Modifiable] [bit],
    rowNum int
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalSalesOrderArchiveCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [SO Number] [nvarchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [Customer Code] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [Customer PO] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Order Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Due Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [Priority] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Standing] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Ship To Address 1] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Ship To Address 2] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Ship To City] [nvarchar](22) NULL,
    [Ship To State] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
    [Ship To Zip] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [How Shipped] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Cert] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Repair Order] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OriginalDueDate] [datetime] NULL,
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderHistoryCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [PrO Number] [varchar](20),
    [Time Stamp] [datetime],
    [Activity Code] [varchar](5),
    [Work Station Code] [varchar](3),
    [Employee Code 1] [varchar](10),
    [Employee Code 2] [varchar](10),
    [Employee Code 3] [varchar](10),
    [Employee Code 4] [varchar](10),
    [Stop Date] [datetime],
    [Stop Time] [datetime],
    [PausedFunctionID] [nvarchar](5),
    [ActivityPairID] [nvarchar](36) 
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalBOMArchiveCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [PrO Number] [nvarchar](20),
    [AP Part Number] [nvarchar](20),
    [Rev] [nvarchar](3),
    [Rqd Quantity] [smallint],
    [Kit] [bit],
    [UOM] [nvarchar](5),
    [Item Number] [int],
    [LineDueDate] [date] 
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalSerialNumberCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [Serial Number] [nvarchar](8) NOT NULL,
    [PrO Number] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Date Packaged] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Cert Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShipPrO] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Date Picked] [datetime] NULL
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalNonConformanceCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [WorkOrder] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [NonConformCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [DepartmentCode] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NULL,
    [Emp] [varchar](10) NULL
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderLotArchiveCorresponding (
    Dataset nvarchar(100),
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [PrO Number] [nvarchar](20),
    [AP Part Number] [nvarchar](20),
    [Lot Number] [nvarchar](12),
    [Replacement] [char](1),
    [Quantity] [int],
    [TimeStamp] [datetime]
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderReworkCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [ReworkNumber] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Originator] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [DueDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Department] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [DefectCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [RefType] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [CAR] [varchar](12) NULL,
    [Comment] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Lot] [varchar](8) NULL,
    [Parent_Lot] [char](1) NULL
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderReworkStepsCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [ReworkNumber] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ReworkLine] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ActionCode] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [ActionComment] [varchar](200) NULL
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderScrapArchiveCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [WorkOrder] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [PartNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Rev] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NULL,
    [DeptCode] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [Emp] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
)

create table ArchiveProject_FinalShipmentArchiveCorresponding (
    ArchiveYear nvarchar(5),
    [PrO Number] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Date Shipped] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Time Shipped] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [How Shipped] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Where Shipped] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [Quantity] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TrackingNumber] [nvarchar](75) NULL
)

print 'ArchiveProject tables created'

GO

/***************
Production Order (pks: pro number)
***************/
drop table if exists #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows
drop table if exists #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates
drop table if exists #FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated

delete from ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates

--#ProdOrderArchiveWithRows:
select

    *
    , row_number() over(partition by a.[Pro Number] order by a.[Pro Number], a.ArchiveYear) [row]

into #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows

from

    ATS_ARCHIVE.dbo.[Production Order] a with(nolock)

--#ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates: distinct WOs in the archive that have more than 1 row in the archive
select distinct 

    t.[PrO Number]

into #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates

from

    #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows t

where

    t.[row] > 1

--#FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated: Rows duplicated in archive table that don't exist in main
select 

    'Rows duplicated in archive table that dont exist in main' Dataset
    , t2.*

into #FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated

from

    #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates t
    inner join #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows t2 on t.[PrO Number] = t2.[PrO Number]

where

    t.[PrO Number] not in (select t.[PrO Number] from [Production Order] t with(nolock))

--ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates: 
insert into ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates (
    ArchiveYear
    , [PrO Number]
    , [SO Number]
    , [SO Line Item]
    , [Priority]
    , [AP Part Number]
    , [Rev]
    , [Order Quantity]
    , [Due Date]
    , [Scheduled Date]
    , [Time Required]
    , [Status]
    , [Parent]
    , [Special Instructions]
    , [Unit Cost]
    , [Order Date]
    , [Open Qty]
    , [Prod Qty]
    , [Discount]
    , [Current Department Code]
    , [Original Due Date]
    , [SO Quantity]
    , [SN OK]
    , [WeldDate]
    , [WeldPriority]
    , [WeldNotes]
    , [KitFlag]
    , [KitNotes]
    , [StockRev]
    , [OutsideJob]
    , [CustPN]
    , [GSSstamp]
    , [TubeNotes]
    , [SOnotes]
    , [ShortDate]
    , [JOB]
    , [SUFFIX]
    , [RemoteWO]
    , [Site]
    , [PART]
    , [KitFlagHighlight]
    , [Modifiable]
    , rowNum 
)

    select

        t.ArchiveYear
        , t.[PrO Number]
        , t.[SO Number]
        , t.[SO Line Item]
        , t.[Priority]
        , t.[AP Part Number]
        , null
        , t.[Order Quantity]
        , t.[Due Date]
        , t.[Scheduled Date]
        , t.[Time Required]
        , t.[Status]
        , t.[Parent]
        , t.[Special Instructions]
        , t.[Unit Cost]
        , t.[Order Date]
        , t.[Open Qty]
        , t.[Prod Qty]
        , t.[Discount]
        , t.[Current Department Code]
        , t.[Original Due Date]
        , t.[SO Quantity]
        , t.[SN OK]
        , t.[WeldDate]
        , t.[WeldPriority]
        , t.[WeldNotes]
        , t.[KitFlag]
        , t.[KitNotes]
        , t.[StockRev]
        , t.[OutsideJob]
        , t.[CustPN]
        , t.[GSSstamp]
        , t.[TubeNotes]
        , t.[SOnotes]
        , null
        , null
        , null
        , null
        , t.[Site]
        , null
        , null
        , null
        , row_number() over(order by t.[PrO Number]) rowNum

    from

        #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows t
        left join [Production Order] t2 with(nolock) on t.[PrO Number] = t2.[PrO Number]

    where

        t2.[PrO Number] is null
        and t.[PrO Number] not in (select [PrO Number] from #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates)

drop table if exists #FinalProdOrderRowsInBoth
drop table if exists #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows
drop table if exists #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates
drop table if exists #FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated

drop index if exists temp_index_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates on ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates

create index temp_index_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates
on ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates([PrO Number]);


There isn't any way anyone can assist you. We don't have any access to your environment to have any idea why its taking so long. SQL performance is affected by many many things, and the actual SQL is only a small part of that (SQL is a declarative language, meaning you describe to the database engine the results you want. But you aren't telling it how to return those results. The how shows up in the execution plan).

I'd suggest, if possible, to create copies of the original tables but with only a fraction of the rows (e.g., 50-100k rather than 50m). Then add print commands after each step in your process, to print out the time it finished and some reference (so you can tell what it refers to) then do dry runs to see what's taking the time. Once that's working OK, try to extend to 1-2 million rows, then 10 million, and ensure it still works before doing your 50 mil.

A few thoughts: (1) How many rows exist in each source table and each intermediate table as the process executes. What percent of archived rows are duplicates? What percent have no matching live production order rows? Knowing how much data you are dealing with at each step along with captured timing is essential information for optimization. (2) In your ROW_NUMBER() calculation, a.[Pro Number] can be omitted in the ORDER BY since it is art of the PARTITION BY. (3) The join between #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates and #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows likely has no supporting indexes.  ...

... (4) The duplicate row logic can be simplified to use the COUNT() window function - SELECT c.* FROM (SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) OVER(...) AS RowCount FROM ATS_ARCHIVE.dbo.[Production Order] a) c WHERE c.RowCount >= 2. (5) During the early preselect stage, it may be best to only work with the key values (Pro Number, ArchiveYear, SO Number, etc.) that can be pulled from indexes and defer full data retrieval to the transfer step. (6) Using nolock is bad practice. If you need stable data without using locks for a mass data transfer operation, to might consider a database snapshot.

Noticing... all of your tables - including the #temp tables - seem to lack any kind of indexes. SQL Server will likely be performing full table scans on them in JOINs. You could try adding appropriate indexes to your #temp tables and after populating them execute UPDATE STATISITICS #YourTempTableName WITH FULLSCAN; so that SQL Server has a better chance of coming up with decent execution plans.

Also worth considering whether this is a situation in which the bcp utility could actually helpful instead of a hindrance.

You're doing a lot of extra copying of data that you don't need to do. You're also missing out on some best practices, like using LEFT JOIN and WHERE [col] IS NULL instead of NOT IN, etc.
Without seeing your environment or an execution plan, here's what I would suggest if we held a code review:
PRINT 'Script started!';

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

DECLARE @Start DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @PrepTime DATETIME;
DECLARE @InsertTime DATETIME;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalSalesOrderArchiveCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderHistoryCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalBOMArchiveCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalSerialNumberCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalNonConformanceCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderLotArchiveCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderReworkCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderReworkStepsCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderScrapArchiveCorresponding;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ArchiveProject_FinalShipmentArchiveCorresponding;

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,[PrO Number] NVARCHAR(20)
    ,[SO Number] NVARCHAR(7)
    ,[SO Line Item] NVARCHAR(10)
    ,Priority NVARCHAR(10)
    ,[AP Part Number] NVARCHAR(20)
    ,Rev VARCHAR(3)
    ,[Order Quantity] INT
    ,[Due Date] DATETIME
    ,[Scheduled Date] DATETIME
    ,[Time Required] SMALLINT
    ,Status NVARCHAR(20)
    ,Parent NVARCHAR(20)
    ,[Special Instructions] NVARCHAR(50)
    ,[Unit Cost] MONEY
    ,[Order Date] DATETIME
    ,[Open Qty] INT
    ,[Prod Qty] INT
    ,Discount REAL
    ,[Current Department Code] NVARCHAR(3)
    ,[Original Due Date] DATETIME
    ,[SO Quantity] INT
    ,[SN OK] BIT
    ,WeldDate DATETIME
    ,WeldPriority SMALLINT
    ,WeldNotes VARCHAR(100)
    ,KitFlag BIT
    ,KitNotes VARCHAR(100)
    ,StockRev VARCHAR(3)
    ,OutsideJob BIT
    ,CustPN VARCHAR(20)
    ,TimeStamp TIMESTAMP
    ,GSSstamp DATETIME
    ,TubeNotes VARCHAR(100)
    ,SOnotes VARCHAR(100)
    ,ShortDate DATETIME
    ,JOB NVARCHAR(30)
    ,SUFFIX NVARCHAR(30)
    ,RemoteWO NVARCHAR(30)
    ,Site VARCHAR(3)
    ,PART NVARCHAR(30)
    ,KitFlagHighlight BIT
    ,CreateDate DATETIME2(7)
    ,CreatedByHostName NVARCHAR(100)
    ,CreatedByLogin NVARCHAR(100)
    ,UpdateDate DATETIME2(7)
    ,UpdatedByHostName NVARCHAR(100)
    ,UpdatedByLogin NVARCHAR(100)
    ,RowPointer NVARCHAR(36)
    ,Modifiable BIT
    ,rowNum INT
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalSalesOrderArchiveCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,[SO Number] NVARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
    ,[Customer Code] NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
    ,[Customer PO] NVARCHAR(15) NULL
    ,[Order Date] DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[Due Date] DATETIME NULL
    ,Priority NVARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,Standing NVARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,[Ship To Address 1] NVARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[Ship To Address 2] NVARCHAR(30) NULL
    ,[Ship To City] NVARCHAR(22) NULL
    ,[Ship To State] NVARCHAR(2) NULL
    ,[Ship To Zip] NVARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,[How Shipped] NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    ,Cert NVARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,[Repair Order] BIT NOT NULL
    ,OriginalDueDate DATETIME NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderHistoryCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,[PrO Number] VARCHAR(20)
    ,[Time Stamp] DATETIME
    ,[Activity Code] VARCHAR(5)
    ,[Work Station Code] VARCHAR(3)
    ,[Employee Code 1] VARCHAR(10)
    ,[Employee Code 2] VARCHAR(10)
    ,[Employee Code 3] VARCHAR(10)
    ,[Employee Code 4] VARCHAR(10)
    ,[Stop Date] DATETIME
    ,[Stop Time] DATETIME
    ,PausedFunctionID NVARCHAR(5)
    ,ActivityPairID NVARCHAR(36)
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalBOMArchiveCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,[PrO Number] NVARCHAR(20)
    ,[AP Part Number] NVARCHAR(20)
    ,Rev NVARCHAR(3)
    ,[Rqd Quantity] SMALLINT
    ,Kit BIT
    ,UOM NVARCHAR(5)
    ,[Item Number] INT
    ,LineDueDate DATE
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalSerialNumberCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,[Serial Number] NVARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
    ,[PrO Number] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,[Date Packaged] DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[Cert Date] DATETIME NULL
    ,ShipPrO NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    ,[Date Picked] DATETIME NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalNonConformanceCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,WorkOrder VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    ,TimeStamp DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,NonConformCode VARCHAR(5) NULL
    ,DepartmentCode VARCHAR(3) NULL
    ,Quantity INT NULL
    ,Emp VARCHAR(10) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderLotArchiveCorresponding
(
    Dataset NVARCHAR(100)
    ,ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,[PrO Number] NVARCHAR(20)
    ,[AP Part Number] NVARCHAR(20)
    ,[Lot Number] NVARCHAR(12)
    ,Replacement CHAR(1)
    ,Quantity INT
    ,TimeStamp DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderReworkCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,ReworkNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,Originator VARCHAR(15) NULL
    ,DueDate VARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,Department VARCHAR(3) NULL
    ,DefectCode VARCHAR(5) NULL
    ,RefType VARCHAR(3) NULL
    ,CAR VARCHAR(12) NULL
    ,Comment VARCHAR(MAX) NULL
    ,Lot VARCHAR(8) NULL
    ,Parent_Lot CHAR(1) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderReworkStepsCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,ReworkNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,ReworkLine INT NOT NULL
    ,ActionCode VARCHAR(5) NULL
    ,ActionComment VARCHAR(200) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderScrapArchiveCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,WorkOrder VARCHAR(20) NULL
    ,PartNumber VARCHAR(20) NULL
    ,Rev VARCHAR(3) NULL
    ,Quantity INT NULL
    ,DeptCode VARCHAR(3) NULL
    ,Emp VARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,TimeStamp DATETIME NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE ArchiveProject_FinalShipmentArchiveCorresponding
(
    ArchiveYear NVARCHAR(5)
    ,[PrO Number] NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,[Date Shipped] DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[Time Shipped] DATETIME NOT NULL
    ,[How Shipped] NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    ,[Where Shipped] NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    ,Quantity INT NOT NULL
    ,TrackingNumber NVARCHAR(75) NULL
);

PRINT 'ArchiveProject tables created';

GO

/***************
Production Order (pks: pro number)
***************/
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated;

--This statement is redundant after you just dropped and recreated the table
--delete from ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates


--This query is an unneeded intermediate step. We can skip it and just use the Archive table in the next query
/*
--#ProdOrderArchiveWithRows:
SELECT
    *
    ,row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.[Pro Number] ORDER BY a.[Pro Number], a.ArchiveYear)
INTO
    #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows
FROM ATS_ARCHIVE.dbo.[Production Order] a WITH (NOLOCK);
--*/


--We can use GROUP BY and HAVING to skip the SELECT DISTINCT
--#ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates: distinct WOs in the archive that have more than 1 row in the archive
SELECT
    t.[PrO Number]
INTO #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates
FROM ATS_ARCHIVE.dbo.[Production Order] t
GROUP BY t.[PrO Number]
HAVING COUNT(t.[PrO Number]) > 1;

CREATE INDEX temp_index_ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates
ON #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates ([PrO Number])

--#FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated is never used, so removing this query, but I left the changes and notes
/*
--#FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated: Rows duplicated in archive table that don't exist in main
SELECT
    Dataset = 'Rows duplicated in archive table that dont exist in main'
    ,t2.*
INTO
    #FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated
FROM #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates              t
INNER JOIN ATS_ARCHIVE.dbo.[Production Order] t2 ON t.[PrO Number] = t2.[PrO Number]
LEFT JOIN [Production Order]                  t3 ON t.[PrO Number] = t3.[PrO Number]
--using NOT IN like this is not a best practice. Just use a LEFT JOIN and check for a NULL value
WHERE --t.[PrO Number] not in (select t.[PrO Number] from [Production Order] t with(nolock))
    t3.[PrO Number] IS NULL;
--*/


--ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates: 
INSERT INTO ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates
(
    ArchiveYear
    ,[PrO Number]
    ,[SO Number]
    ,[SO Line Item]
    ,Priority
    ,[AP Part Number]
    ,Rev
    ,[Order Quantity]
    ,[Due Date]
    ,[Scheduled Date]
    ,[Time Required]
    ,Status
    ,Parent
    ,[Special Instructions]
    ,[Unit Cost]
    ,[Order Date]
    ,[Open Qty]
    ,[Prod Qty]
    ,Discount
    ,[Current Department Code]
    ,[Original Due Date]
    ,[SO Quantity]
    ,[SN OK]
    ,WeldDate
    ,WeldPriority
    ,WeldNotes
    ,KitFlag
    ,KitNotes
    ,StockRev
    ,OutsideJob
    ,CustPN
    ,GSSstamp
    ,TubeNotes
    ,SOnotes
    ,ShortDate
    ,JOB
    ,SUFFIX
    ,RemoteWO
    ,Site
    ,PART
    ,KitFlagHighlight
    ,Modifiable
    ,rowNum
)
SELECT
    t.ArchiveYear
    ,t.[PrO Number]
    ,t.[SO Number]
    ,t.[SO Line Item]
    ,t.Priority
    ,t.[AP Part Number]
    ,NULL
    ,t.[Order Quantity]
    ,t.[Due Date]
    ,t.[Scheduled Date]
    ,t.[Time Required]
    ,t.Status
    ,t.Parent
    ,t.[Special Instructions]
    ,t.[Unit Cost]
    ,t.[Order Date]
    ,t.[Open Qty]
    ,t.[Prod Qty]
    ,t.Discount
    ,t.[Current Department Code]
    ,t.[Original Due Date]
    ,t.[SO Quantity]
    ,t.[SN OK]
    ,t.WeldDate
    ,t.WeldPriority
    ,t.WeldNotes
    ,t.KitFlag
    ,t.KitNotes
    ,t.StockRev
    ,t.OutsideJob
    ,t.CustPN
    ,t.GSSstamp
    ,t.TubeNotes
    ,t.SOnotes
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,t.Site
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,rowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.[PrO Number])
FROM ATS_ARCHIVE.dbo.[Production Order] t
LEFT JOIN [Production Order]            t2 ON t.[PrO Number] = t2.[PrO Number]
LEFT JOIN #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates   t3 ON t.[PrO Number] = t3.[PrO Number]
WHERE t2.[PrO Number] IS NULL
      --and t.[PrO Number] not in (select [PrO Number] from #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates)
      AND t3.[PrO Number] IS NULL;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FinalProdOrderRowsInBoth;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ProdOrderArchiveWithRows;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #ProdOrderArchiveDuplicates;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #FinalProdOrderRowsDuplicated;

DROP INDEX IF EXISTS temp_index_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates
ON ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates;


CREATE INDEX temp_index_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates
ON ArchiveProject_FinalProdOrderNonDuplicates ([PrO Number]);

Just remember 50M rows starts to add up very quickly when you start making extra copies in TempDB.
If you post an actual execution query plan, we might be able to help you tune a little bit more. But I suspect there is a lot of room for improvement by eliminating some of the redundant tables you're populating. Maybe you could create views for some of them.
